# How to select similar values together in same query?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the database as below, i need to get all the zeros and ones in separate list from the below table, that is to get all the zero together in a column and all the ones together in separate column

database

```
| id | value |
-------------
| 1  |   0   |
| 2  |   1   |
| 3  |   0   |
| 4  |   1   |
```

expected result

```
| sp.id | stop | st.id | start|
-------------------------------
|   1   |   0  |   2   |   1  |
|   3   |   0  |   4   |   1  |
```

or

```
| id | value |
-------------
| 1  |   0   |
| 3  |   0   |


| id | value |
-------------
| 2  |   1   |
| 4  |   1   |
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT a.id AS sp.id, a.value AS stop, b.id AS st.id, b.value AS start
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE = 0) a
LEFT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE = 1) b
ON a.id = b.id
UNION
SELECT a.id AS sp.id, a.value AS stop, b.id AS st.id, b.value AS start
FROM (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE = 0) a
RIGHT JOIN (SELECT * FROM TABLE WHERE = 1) b
ON a.id = b.id
```

Answer (score 0):

For your expected result 1, you can use `case`

```
select case when value=0 then id end as spid,
       case when value=0 then value end as stop,
       case when value=1 then id end as stid,
       case when value=1 then value end as start
from yourtable.
```

But you will get `NULL` for empty rows as shown below. If that is fine, you can use the above query. If it is a `String` you can use `MAX()` or `MIN()` with `group by` to avoid this empty values.

OUTPUT

```
+------+------+------+-------+
| spid | stop | stid | start |
+------+------+------+-------+
| 1    | 0    |      |       |
+------+------+------+-------+
|      |      | 2    | 1     |
+------+------+------+-------+
| 3    | 0    |      |       |
+------+------+------+-------+
|      |      | 4    | 1     |
+------+------+------+-------+
```

For you expected output 2, you can directly use `UNION ALL`

```
select id,value from test where value=0
union all
select id,value from test where value=1
```

OUTPUT

```
+----+-------+
| id | value |
+----+-------+
| 1  | 0     |
+----+-------+
| 3  | 0     |
+----+-------+
| 2  | 1     |
+----+-------+
| 4  | 1     |
+----+-------+
```

[**CHECK DEMO HERE**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=dc28fbf0ad743951dfd72a55c07c9bce)